# Celery - How to send task from remote machine?

Tags: python, celery

We have a server running celery workers and a Redis queue. The tasks are defined on that server.
I need to be able to call these tasks from a remote machine.
I know that it is done using `send_task` but I still haven't figured out HOW? How do I tell `send_task` where the queue is? Where do I pass connection params (or whatever needed)?  I've been looking for hours and all I can find is this:

```
from celery.execute import send_task
send_task('tasks.add')
```

Well, that means that I need `celery` on my calling machine as well. But what else do I need to set up?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This may be a way:
Creating a Celery object and using send_task from that object, the object can have the configuration to find the broker.

```
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery()
celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
celery.send_task('tasks.add', (2,2))
```

celeryconfig is a file containing the celery configuration, there are other ways set config on the celery object.

Comment: I recently had a similar problem where by the send_task invocation was correct, however the task was not found by the server. I was receiving an error "Received unregistered task of type... ". To solve this, in your tasks definitions decorator add the 'name' argument. Example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/johnpaulhayes/8403108)

Comment: OK, that's great man... now a real test.  How do you utilize a callback with that so I can get the actual value returned from the task??

Comment: Something that threw me off for a few hours was that I needed to define which queue my producing script was putting the 'jobs'. ended up with `celery.send_task('tasks.the_remote_task_name', ([arguments,...]),
queue='name_of_queue')` got from this [link](https://www.marshut.net/ipwtin/sending-tasks-from-a-machine-and-running-celery-workers-on-another-machine.html)

Comment: Thanks @johnpaulhayes - your Gist https://gist.github.com/johnpaulhayes/8403108 did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to define routing rules, the most general of which is the custom router object.  In all cases, the caller just provides a `routing_key` parameter in `send_task`, `delay` or `apply_async` and the router determines which queue to send the task into.

Comment: Thanks, but this leads me back to the start. Where do I define this route key? Do I need a config file on the calling machine? Or is there something else I need to configure before calling `send_task`?

Comment: The examples in http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#id13 show how to create a config file, and how to define routes in the config file. You do need the config file on the calling machine since your broker is REDIS.  (If you were using AMQP, you would have the option to define routing rules in the Rabbit layer instead).

Comment: The doc you mentioned doesn't explain how to tell send_task to use redis. It only explains how to setup the worker. By doing that, send_task returns "Connection refused" error(at least for me)

Answer (score 0):

on the remote machine, start up celery with the broker_url pointing to the machine you want to run the tasks on. Then just submit the tasks (if you have specific queues to submit to, then add the appropriate routing keys).

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest update, this method is one of the app methods.
for example:

```
from project.celery_general import general_app

# general app is celery app you defined
general_app.send_task(name='your_task_name', *args, **kwargs)
```

[refrence](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.send_task)

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19257867/6056788) by [Leonardo Ruiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2860243/leonardo-ruiz) worked for me.
However his code doesn't give a sample of the celery config provided. Also, incase your task names have a prefix then you have to provide the complete path.

Sharing the code below for others.

1. I am using Redis as the broker, you can replace with the broker of your choice.
2. If your task doesn't have any prefix then you can simply pass **'tasks.add'** as the input to **send_task**.

Code

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('celery_app',
             broker='redis://localhost:6379/0',
)
data = (2,2) # sample data
app.send_task('myapp.subfolder.celery_app.tasks.add', data)
```

Answer (score -7):

What you found was right.

```
from celery.execute import send_task

send_task('tasks.add')
```

If any args needed

```
send_task('tasks.add', kwargs={'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```