# Celery send_task() method

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I have my API, and some endpoints need to forward requests to Celery. Idea is to have specific API service that basically only instantiates Celery client and uses send_task() method, and seperate service(workers) that consume tasks. Code for task definitions should be located in that worker service. Basicaly seperating celery app (API) and celery worker to two seperate services.
I dont want my API to know about any celery task definitions, endpoints only need to use `celery_client.send_task('some_task', (some_arguments))`. So on one service i have my API, an on other service/host I have celery code base where my celery worker will execute tasks.

I came across this great article that describes what I want to do.
https://medium.com/@tanchinhiong/separating-celery-application-and-worker-in-docker-containers-f70fedb1ba6d
and this post [Celery - How to send task from remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433071/celery-how-to-send-task-from-remote-machine)

I need help on how to create routes for tasks from the API? I was expecting for `celery_client.send_task()` to have `queue=` keyword, but it does not. I need to have 2 queues, and two workers that will consume content from these two queues.

Commands for my workers:

```
celery -A <path_to_my_celery_file>.celery_client worker --loglevel=info -Q queue_1
celery -A <path_to_my_celery_file>.celery_client worker --loglevel=info -Q queue_2
```

I have also visited celery "Routing Tasks" documentation, but it is still unclear to me how to establish this communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your API side should hold the router. I guess it's not an issue because it is only a map of task -> queue (aka send `task1` to `queue1`).

In other words, your `celery_client` should have [task_routes](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-routes) like:

```
task_routes = {
    'mytasks.some_task': 'queue_1',
    'mytasks.some_other_task': 'queue_2',
}
```

Comment: @mehekek did it answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! (SO deleted my comment)

Comment: @mehekek you can thank me by upvoting & accepting the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Celery does have a `queue` parameter for `send_task()` because it takes the same kwargs as `apply_async()`

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.send_task
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async

```
celery_client.send_task(
    'some_task',
    args=(some_arguments,),
    queue='your_queue'
)
```